# What is shakeout testing?

Tags: terminology

What is shakeout testing? Googling gives things such as,

> To identify an initial test which
>   verifies that a load has been
>   successful and all software is
>   accessible and functioning as
>   expected.

But what does that mean? What load? "Functioning as expected" sounds like a lot of other testing is happening, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often the terms "Shakeout (or Shakedown) Testing", "Smoke Testing", and "Sanity Testing" are used synonymously, with "Shakeout/Shakedown" being the least common of the terms.

**Smoke Test**

A subset of all defined/planned test cases that cover the main functionality of a component or system, to ascertain that the most crucial functions of a program work, but not bothering with finer details.  A daily build and smoke test is among industry best practices.  [ISTQB]

Comment: My understanding is that a "smoke test" was the first step of a "shakedown cruise" - you ran your engines (not in gear) in the harbor, and the smoke rose from the smoke stacks. If it didn't explode after a while, you knew you could try actually putting the engines in gear. Chances are you would have to make some calibrations after the smoke test before putting it in gear though. Note the historical accuracy and etymology typically have little bearing on day to day usage, so they very well may have merged. :)

Comment: "Smoke test" is also used in plumbing, to figure out where the holes are, so you can start fixing them.

Comment: I selected this as the "best" answer because, after working for a client for several months, this is the meaning that most closely matches how they use the term.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it.  There is no ISO standard definition for a shakeout test for software.  People have all kinds of terms for distinguishing one kind of testing from another but everyone uses them differently.  It's more important to understand that how you test depends on your goals (e.g. accepting a customized product before writing a big check, making sure a change works before you check it in to your version control system, or making sure a build installs and performs essential functions before you unleash your entire test team on it) and circumstances (e.g. product has been completely rewritten, an independent subsystem was refactored but its interface did not change, or a developer made a small, isolated tweak that feels low-risk because you reviewed the source code).

Names are just names.  In our business, what matters is understanding why you do what you do.

Comment: Wouldn't worry about it? How can you interview a position without an extensive supply of buzzwords?!

Comment: That's true.  In an interview, just precede your definition with, "At my last job, we used that term to mean..." and then say something that sounds defensible.

Comment: For those of you in India, if you are looking for answers to interview questions, you may want to join www.qualitytesting.info.   They seem to focus a lot on interview questions.

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm already working for a client who uses the term. I wanted to understand it better before I went onsite for some training. Now that I've had some experience, I realize they use it in the same sense as "smoke test".

Answer (score 2):

I believe it comes from a Shakedown cruise:

> Shakedown cruise is a nautical term in which the performance of a ship is tested. Shakedown cruises are also used to familiarize the ship's crew with operation of the craft.

So essentially, it's a full blown run of the software, but you're not yet doing mission critical work. I personally would consider a beta stage to be a shakeout test. This is especially true considering the following:

> These test cruises are sometimes made with passengers traveling at a discount.

Comment: Nice explanation, and probably right too.

Comment: I'd combine this with Joe's note to cover it, a Shakedown seems just like a Smoke Test to me and has been the same in my worlds.

Answer (score -1):

**Smoke Testing** is done by developer to check the build is stable enough so that it can be send to testing team for testing.

**Shakeout Testing:** Shake out testing is done before the testing starts to make sure that applications are pointing to correct urls and data is flowing and also to make sure applications are pointing to correct environments.

**Sanity Testing:** It is done whenever there is a small changes are done in application to make sure that the application is up and running and correctly working.

Comment: I think these are very company/industry specific definitions.